# How do you listen for two asynchronous, attached event handlers?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to listen for two javascript events. Both need to happen, but I don't know what order in which they will occur. I don't want to run my code until both of these happen. Can I use deferred events together with jQuery's event handler attaching functions?

Specifically I want to wait until a bootstrap modal with remote, loaded content has finished showing and loading.

Clicking on this hyperlink shows the modal, loads the page in the hyperlink using jquery's `load` method, and inserts the loaded page's content into the modal.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Click Here</a>
```

The target modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My failed attempt to attach the event listeners and use promises to know when both events have fired. The issue here I think is that promises are telling me the listeners are attached, not that the events have fired.

```
var loaded = $(".modal").on('loaded.bs.modal', function(evt) {
    console.log("content loaded");
}).promise();
var shown = $(".modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(evt) {
    console.log("modal visible");
}).promise();

$.when(loaded, shown).done(function(load, show) {
    console.log("content loaded and modal visible");
});
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/uU0jLHOdtr) on bootply

Comment: Try http://www.bootply.com/YWcJsaXbpq

Comment: @PSL using `resolve()` works perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mr.Dave, from what I can tell, it looks like the `shown` event will always fire after the `loaded` event. There's no reason to finish displaying the modal if there's no content to display. I think you'd be safe just listening for the `shown` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise) returns a deferred promise for the `fx` queue. As you're not actually waiting for the `fx` queue, there's no reason to use that particular method here.

Consulting the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> **show.bs.modal** - This event fires immediately when the `show` instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.
>
> **shown.bs.modal** - This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.
>
> **loaded.bs.modal** - This event is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option.

Promises are one-time use. Once they're resolved, you need to produce a new promise.

If you know that events are going to occur in a specific order, relying on that order is often enough. For example, if the order is always:

1. show
2. loaded
3. shown

then attaching an event handler to the `shown` event is enough because it'll always occur after the `loaded` event.

---

<sub>My interpretation of the documentation is that the `shown` event will always be fired after the `loaded` event (why show something that's not there yet?), which would mean you could just listen for the `shown` event, and ignore `loaded` altogether.</sub>

---

As I'm not 100% sure of the *actual* behavior, I will assume for the sake of this post that the order could also be:

1. show
2. shown
3. loaded

I've included `show` in the list because it's a consistent starting point. You won't get `shown` or `loaded` events until *after* the `show` event has fired. This is helpful because you can use it to generate new deferreds.

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var $this,
        data;
    $this = $(this);
    data = $this.data();
    if (data.shownDeferred) {
        //if this modal had been opened before, but never finished
        //showing it should be cancelled
        data.shownDeferred.reject();
    }
    data.shownDeferred = $.Deferred();
    if (data.loadedDeferred) {
        //if this modal had been opened before, but never loaded
        //it should be cancelled
        data.loadedDeferred.reject();
    }
    data.loadedDeferred = $.Deferred();

    $.when(data.shownDeferred, data.loadedDeferred).then(function () {
        $this.trigger('yourcustomeventname');
    });
}).on('loaded.bs.modal', function () {
    var dfd;
    dfd = $(this).data('loadedDeferred');
    if (dfd) {
        dfd.resolve();
    }
}).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var dfd;
    dfd = $(this).data('shownDeferred');
    if (dfd) {
        dfd.resolve();
    }
});
```

With the above setup, you an set the modal to trigger your own custom event when both the `loaded` and `shown` events have finished firing.

---

<sub>**Warning** I haven't tested any of this code, so it may be buggy</sub>

Comment: Including show was a smart idea. I typically see 'loaded' before 'shown', but I don't believe there's any reason for bootstrap to order the model's animation and jQuery's load. I'm testing this approach now, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This works great. As you mentioned, generating new Deferreds instead of promises allows this to trigger new events repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, Deferreds/Promises are a sledge hammer to crack a nut. Even if the order of events was not known, the whole thing could be solved with booleans, not Promises.

However, the order of events *is* known. Running a **[test](http://www.bootply.com/LEKScuh5bI)**, you can see that an initial "show" behaves differently from subsequent "shows". The events, in order, are as follows :

- on first show - 'show', 'loaded', 'shown'
- on subsequent shows - 'show', 'shown'

In other words, `loaded` is a one-off event, and `shown` is reliably last.

Therefore, you can simply listen for `shown`.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //Do awesome stuff here
});
```

If you want to suppress further "shows" before the modal has shown, then it's slightly more involved but not too bad - something like this maybe :

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data('modal');
    if (!data) {
        data = $this.data('modal') = {};
    }
    if(!data.pending) {
        data.pending = true;
        $this.one('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            data.pending = false;
            //Do awesome stuff here
        });
    }
});
```

With a bit more thought, that would probably simplify down.